# Trying to create sequential hyperlink to worksheets in the same book

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a summary page, and 50+ other pages, numbered 1-50. what I'm trying to do is create a hyperlink that will go to the correct sheet when clicked. I've got it working for one, but when I drag it down it won't shift the sheet number.

At the moment I'm using this formula

```
=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT(SheetNames!A1&"!"&"A1"), "Details")
```

However its not working.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need hyperlinks?  Can you get by using the built in WorkSheet Index?

Right click one of the Navigation Buttons, the little arrows on the bottom left of the Excel window.  This will bring up the list of worksheets in your workbook.  You can select from the list and navigate directly to that worksheet.

With this method, there is no editing of the hyperlinks if you add or delete a worksheet.

If you HAVE TO use hyperlinks, try this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#'Sheet"&ROW()&"'!A1","Sheet"&ROW())
```

This assumes your sheet names are Sheet1, Sheet2, etc... and you will be pointing to cell A1 in the linked sheet.  Your links to the sheets will be controlled by the ROW() function (i.e. the link on row 7 points to Sheet7)